# Teamcity build trigger exclude all but some

Tags: teamcity, build-triggers

I'm using teamcity to perform my builds.

within my repository there are multiple projects that uses different folders. e.g. like this:

```
└root
  ├project1
  │  └files
  ├project2
  │  └files
  └project3
     └files
```

I have 3 lanes that should all here just on there own folder.

The current trigger configuration for *project2* looks like this:

```
-:*/project1/*
-:*/project3/*
+:*/project2/*
```

but I don't want to explicit add all projects to the trigger configuration of every project. therefore I would like to say s.th. like

```
-:IGNORE_EVERYTHING
+:*/project2/*
```

which means I just want to list the folder that SHOULD get monitored but not exclude all others. When I just use the last line of the above the two other folders gets monitored as well.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation [Configuring VCS Triggers](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Configuring+VCS+Triggers#ConfiguringVCSTriggers-VCSTriggerRules):

> When entering rules, please note that as soon as you enter any "+" rule, TeamCity will remove the default "include all" setting. To include all the files, use "+:." rule.

You don't need any exclusion rule. Just insert:

```
+:*/project2/*
```

in Trigger Rules and you should be good.